# How to limit API scope in Odoo with a certain model?

Tags: permissions, odoo

Is it possible to limit a user's permissions scope to prevent him from accessing (using the external API mechanism) all the models except a few ones?

As the very first test, I tried to block all the models:

- create a brand new and empty Group (User types/API) - no Access Rights or Record Rules added;
- add a user to it;
- remove the user from any other Groups (like "Internal User");

But, when I log in and request a model using API calls - it works, just like all the needed permissions have been granted!..

The user looks like this:
[image]

...and the only Group it belongs to:
[image]

[image]

**UPDATE**:
I request the model just like (Python):

```
common = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/common'.format(url))

uid = common.authenticate(db, username, password, {})
if uid:
    print("authentication succeeded")

    models = xmlrpc.client.ServerProxy('{}/xmlrpc/2/object'.format(url))

    api_result = models.execute(db, uid, password, 'custom.object', 'custom_method', {'custom_info': {'test_key': 'test_value'}})
```

...and get the proper response of `custom_method()`

Comment: What do you mean by "request a model"? Can you share you little script using the api with this user?

Comment: Just added as the update, please check